# only after refactoring packages names, Consider defining a bean of type * in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

this piece of code has been working perfectly, i just refactored packages names and the spring context can no more inject this bean.
I am sure btw that the new packages names still matches the **@ComponentScan** scope

```
@Repository("tenantsConfigRepository")
public interface TenantsConfigRepository extends JpaRepository<TenantsConfig, Long> {
    public TenantsConfig deleteByName(String name);
}
```

```
@Service
public class TenantsConfigService {

    TenantsConfigRepository tenantsConfigRepository;


    @Autowired
    public TenantsConfigService(TenantsConfigRepository tenantsConfigRepository) {
        this.tenantsConfigRepository = tenantsConfigRepository;
    }

    public List<TenantsConfig> findAll() {
        return tenantsConfigRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<TenantsConfig> find(long id) {
        return tenantsConfigRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(TenantsConfig tenantsConfig) {
        tenantsConfigRepository.save(tenantsConfig);
    }

    public void delete(TenantsConfig tenantsConfig) {
        tenantsConfigRepository.delete(tenantsConfig);
    }

    public void deleteByName(String name) {
        tenantsConfigRepository.deleteByName(name);
    }
}
```

Application failed to start and printing this text

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
**************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.admin.service.TenantsConfigService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Be sure that your component scan covers the packages after the renaming

Comment: Pleaes add your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class AND include all the package declaration.Next to that please include the full stacktrace (mightneed to restart the app using `--debug`).

Comment: I am already using a spring-boot application, and ```@SpringBootApplication``` exists on the root of the project (and so ```@ComponentScan```).
i am using multiple datasources, and i am defining no one in my application.properties i think i am defining other scopes for the EntityManager i will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys for responding, I figured it out, i was using a datasource from a configuration class, those configurations were scoped to be used to specific packages, i just changed the`basePackages` attribute to match the new packages names.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.admin", entityManagerFactoryRef = "adminEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "adminTransactionManager")
```

and

```
em.setPackagesToScan("com.example.admin.entity");
```

em refers to EntityManager